# Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to move from MySQL to Oracle and one of my queries originally looks like this

```
SELECT t1.table_name 
FROM db_available AS t1 
INNER JOIN db_user_access AS t2 
    ON t1.id=t2.db_id 
WHERE t2.user_id=100 AND t2.expires >= NOW();
```

However, when I run the same query in ORACLE with a minor change...

```
SELECT t1.table_name 
FROM db_available AS t1 
INNER JOIN db_user_access AS t2 
    ON t1.id=t2.db_id 
WHERE t2.user_id=100 
    AND t2.expires >= SYSDATE;
```

it gives me the following error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended 00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

The Oracle SQL Developer tool underlines a problem in the part of the statement

> AS t1

I read some other questions that mentioned placing parenthesis around certain parts of the statement for Oracle, however I am just a beginner and don't fully understand Oracle databases yet so I don't really understand where to put them or if they are even needed in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle) you don't need to specify `as` when aliasing a table:

```
SELECT t1.table_name 
FROM db_available t1 
INNER JOIN db_user_access t2 
    ON t1.id=t2.db_id 
WHERE t2.user_id=100 
    AND t2.expires >= SYSDATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.table_name 
FROM db_available t1, db_user_access t2 
WHERE t1.id=t2.db_id 
  AND t2.user_id=100 
  AND t2.expires >= SYSDATE;
```

Acording to oracle documentation you also don't need to use explicit joins.

Comment: But it is highly recommended that he does, being the ANSI standard

Comment: Sure. To avoid problems if there is the need to change de database. Correct if I'm wrong, but oracle tells to not use explicty joins cause their optimizer works better without them.